# Can't get libcurl to work on Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am trying to follow this tutorial: 
http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/

> Now go to VC++ Directories > Library directories. Add the Debug
>   directory containing curllib_static.lib, curllib.dll and curllib.lib
>   (C:\Users\Édouard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\LibCurl\lib\Debug).

I don't have a Debug directory. Where do I get it? Thanks

Comment: Did you compile a `libcurl` library from source? Then you should have a `Debug` directory.

Comment: no I didn't try that yet. what exactly has to be compiled? I read this on the internet a few times but the file doesn't seem to be with me (normally downloaded the windows version)